# Swift Timer Control

Tags: swift, timer

```
var timer = Timer()
var number = 0

func countUp() {
     number += 1
    print(number)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "countUp", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

Hello there
I added the timer to the project. I have 5 view controllers in my project. I'm starting the first view controller and I want to stop at another view controller. How can I do it ?

Comment: Is the goal to have the timer stop when another view controller appears and your first view goes away?

Comment: So, what are you trying to achieve is to navigate to the next viewController every 1 second, right?